# Can't return model when deleting one document from Spring MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to find and remove a specific document from a MongoRepository in a Spring program. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.delete) gives the examples of `Person deleteSingleByLastname(String lastname)` and `Optional<Person> deleteByBirthdate(Date birthdate)` as methods that could be used to accomplish this. However, when I attempt to do this, I get the following error message: `class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class [my model class]`. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076537/), which is similar, but it does not mention the `deleteSingleBy...` keyword from the documentation that I'm trying to use.

Here is what I have tried:

```java
@Repository
public interface SomeModelRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeModel, String> {
  // This one works
  List<SomeModel> removeByKey(String key);

  //...and all of these don't
  Optional<SomeModel> removeByKey(String key);
  Optional<SomeModel> removeSingleByKey(String key);
  Optional<SomeModel> deleteByKey(String key);
  Optional<SomeModel> deleteSinglByKey(String key);

  @Nullable
  SomeModel removeByKey(String key);
  @Nullable
  SomeModel removeSingleByKey(String key);
  @Nullable
  SomeModel deleteByKey(String key);
  @Nullable
  SomeModel deleteSingleByKey(String key);
}
```

Why is this not working? I am using a version of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` from February of 2020.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Looks like 2.2.4; I tried updating some things but I'm not the most experienced with Maven and I ended up breaking everything even worse

Answer (score 1):

- This support is present in `3.0.1.RELEASE` version `spring-data-mongodb`

```
   Changes in version 3.0.0.M3 (2020-02-12)
   ----------------------------------------
   DATAMONGO-1997 - Add support to return the single deleted item 
   for a deleteBy query method.
```

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/changelog.txt
- As per https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb, if you use Feb 2020 version of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`, it brings `2.2.3.RELEASE` version `spring-data-mongodb`
- Even if you use the latest version of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`, it does not bring the `3.0.1.RELEASE` version of `spring-data-mongodb`
- Try specifying this directly as dependency

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete by something different from key, this will return the number of documents deleted since you can have more than one document matching.
Back to your issue, spring-data is trying to cast the number of documents returned by the delete query which is a Long to your model object.
So, just change return types to Long

Comment: I am aware that the delete method can work this way. However, the documentation also claims that it should be possible to have a `deleteSingle` method that returns the document that was deleted. I cannot change the return type to Long, because that would not return the document that was deleted.